# Input com Link para "modal"

Tags: javascript, html, css, jogos

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto com sudoku, e eu gostaria de mostrar um "modal" com as possibilidades toda vez que o usuario clicar em alguma célula.

Esse site ilustra bem o que eu preciso: https://www.geniol.com.br/logica/sudoku/

[image: modal com possibilidades, sudoku]

Como posso fazer isso?

(Estou utilizando input nas células)

Comment: Sua pergunta é um pouco superficial. Há centenas de possibilidades. O ideal seria você iniciar alguma coisa tentando implementar algum plugin de modal e chamar no evento de clique do input. E então, se houver algum problema/impedimento, você poderia postar aqui com o código e etc.

Comment: Por favor, coloque um exemplo de sua aplicação no http://jsfiddle.net para que possamos entender exatamente o que você tem de forma que seja possível sugerir uma implementação ou até implementa-la talvez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu que desenvolvi o Sudoku do Geniol.

O funcionamento é o seguinte: eu pego a posição da célula que o usuário clicou e calculo o X, Y do meio dela e movo a posição central do div do numpad pra aquele lugar.

O trecho do código é esse (usamos CoffeeScript):

```
# $cell é o div que tem o número que foi clicado e $numpad é o div do modal

left = $cell.position().left  - $numpad.width() / 2 + $cell.width() / 2
top = $cell.position().top - $numpad.height() / 2  + $cell.height() / 2

$numpad.css
    top: top, left: left

$numpad.addClass 'clicked'
```

E o CSS:

```
#numpad {
    opacity: 0
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
}

#numpad.clicked { 
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
}
```